# Why doesn't .append() method work on strings, don't they behave like lists?

Tags: string, python-3.x, append

Why does this statement produce an error even though a string is actually a list of character constants?

```
string_name = ""  
string_name.append("hello word")
```

The reason I expect this to work is because when we use for-loop, we are allowed to use this statement:

```
for i in string_name:  
    ...
```

I think `string_name` is considered as a list here(?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's what they teach you in an algorithms and data structures class, that deal with algorithmic languages (unreal) rather than real programming languages, in Python, a string is a string, and a list is a list, they're different objects, you can "append" to a string using what is called string concatenation (which is basically an addition operation on strings):

```
string_name = "hello"  
string_name = string_name + " world"
print(string_name) # => "hello world"
```

Or a shorthand concatenation:

```
string_name = "hello"
string_name += " world"
print(string_name) # => "hello world"
```

Lists and strings belong to this type called `iterable`. `iterable`s are as they're name suggests, iterables, meaning you can iterate through them with the key word `in`, but that doesn't mean they're the same type of objects:

```
for i in '123': # valid, using a string
for i in [1, 2, 3]: # valid, using a list
for i in (1, 2, 3): # valid, using a tuple
for i in 1, 2, 3: # valid, using an implicit-tuple
# all valid, all different types
```

I strongly recommend that you read the [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) and/or take the [Python's Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/).

From Docs Glossary:

> **iterable**  
>   An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as **`list`**, **`str`**, and **`tuple`**) and some non-sequence types like **`dict`**, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()` method. Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed (`zip()`, `map()`, `…`). When an iterable object is passed as an argument to the built-in function `iter()`, it returns an iterator for the object. This iterator is good for one pass over the set of values. When using iterables, it is usually not necessary to call `iter()` or deal with iterator objects yourself. The for statement does that automatically for you, creating a temporary unnamed variable to hold the iterator for the duration of the loop. See also iterator, sequence, and generator.
>   More about [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

Comment: Oh now i get it . So it just means that both these data types are iterable but that they are not the same

Comment: @PiyushKumar Exactly, much like integers and floats(reals), they are both numbers and can be manipulated by arithemetic operators, but they're different in the language's core.

Comment: `+=` creates a copy of the original string before appending, right? Requires O(n) time. Is there no way to simply append to an existing string without copying it?

Answer (score -4):

```
Error is given when u try to append strings.So better first take list and then convert list to string.Code :

               n='qwerty'
               for i in range(1):
                   temp=[]
                   temp.append(n[-3:])
                   temp.append('t')
                   newtemp=' '
                   newtemp=temp[i]+temp[i+1]
                   print(newtemp)
```

Output:rtyt